# Laravel datatable invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, response, middleware

Everything work fine on code below to fetch user logs:

js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table =$('#systemLogs').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "language": {
            "url": "/datatables/media/plug-in/Persian.json"
        },
        ajax: '{!! url('/admin/systemLogs/data/systemLogsDataTable') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'message_text', name: 'message_text' },
            { data: 'remote_addr', name: 'remote_addr' },
            { data: 'log_created_at', name: 'management_logs.created_at' },
            { data: 'log_updated_at', name: 'management_logs.updated_at' },
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/systemLogs/data/systemLogsDataTable','SystemLogsController@systemLogsDataTable');

public function systemLogsDataTable()
{
    $logs= ManagementLog::select('management_logs.message_text','management_logs.remote_addr','management_logs.created_at as log_created_at','management_logs.updated_at as log_updated_at','managements.name')->leftJoin('managements','management_logs.management_id','=','managements.id');
    return Datatables::of($logs)->make(true);
}
```

It works fine for me but when I want to fetch just 2 fields from database it will give me

> DataTables warning:table id=systemLogs - invalid JSON response.

but some times it will work ok.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table =$('#systemLogs').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "language": {
            "url": "/datatables/media/plug-in/Persian.json"
        },
        ajax: '{!! url('/admin/systemLogs/data/systemLogsDataTable') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'message_text', name: 'message_text' },
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

I have understood which the problem is from middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next,$guard = 'admin')
{
    if(!Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
        return redirect('/administrator/logout');
    }else{
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

when I changed it to:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next,$guard = 'admin')
{
    return $next($request);
}
```

It works fine so it means the problem is from AJAX.
what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's because if you're not logged into application the response is gonna be a redirect and this is a invalid AJAX response, you can try this to handle redirect response:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table =$('#systemLogs').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "language": {
            "url": "/datatables/media/plug-in/Persian.json"
        },
        ajax: function(data, callback, settings) {
            // make a regular ajax request
            $.get('{!! url('/admin/systemLogs/data/systemLogsDataTable') !!}', function(res) {
                if(res.redirect)
                    window.location.href = res.redirect;

                callback({
                    data: JSON.parse(res)
                });
            });
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'message_text', name: 'message_text' },
            { data: 'remote_addr', name: 'remote_addr' },
            { data: 'log_created_at', name: 'management_logs.created_at' },
            { data: 'log_updated_at', name: 'management_logs.updated_at' },
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: No i have to become login before to see this page. I said if the number of selected fields is more than 3 the there is no error or if i make false server side then there is no error again. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with make false server side? @ehsankhodayar

Comment: When you put serverside true it will fetch data every time from server for example on search or on pagination and the other but when you put it on false it will fech all data from database at the first time then the other things like search or pagination and the other is not serverver side and it is client side.

Comment: But errors appears when you fetch the data from the server, it doesn't? @ehsankhodayar

Comment: It will fetch data from server in the both mode but when you put it in server  mode it will fetch data from server every time forexample searching or pagination but when it is not on server mode it will fetch all date note all data from database at the first time and it is not suitble.

Comment: I have the same problem, If you can give an idea how to solve this issue @ehsankhodayar thanks

Comment: @ِAllloush you can describe your problem?

Comment: It is a bug on this plugin and after this problem i've tried to do all of these oprations on my self and don't use this kind of plugins.

Comment: Also i advice to you make your own data table it is not very hard and just need a bit jQuery and css knowledge and for pagination you can use laravel pagination or do it with jQuery.

Comment: @JoseRojas thanks man :). My problem and the question are twins, same issue. when I have to load all categories from categories table which has only 2 column, I run into this problem which is a redirection response to login page then login page redirect to index page so the result is invalid ajax response, but other pages which has  more than 4 columns every thing is working fine. I switch serverside=false but I know it is bad solution

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using php artisan serve? I think yes, so I suggest you use homestead/valet or any apache/nginx stack.

It's been a known weird bug of the package where Laravel randomly returns redirect/404 response when using artisan serve.

-- Edit --

Updated the package documentation and advise the known bug. 
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#php-artisan-serve-bug